# Difference between mysqli_error and mysqli_stmt_error

Tags: php, mysql

Am I right in thinking that `mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)` returns the error of that specific query and not the last MySQL error? For example, would the following work?

```
...

$stmt1->execute();
$stmt2->execute();

echo $stmt1->error // $stmt1 error
echo $stmt2->error // $stmt2 error

...
```

Or is `mysqli_stmt_error()` the same as `mysqli_error()`, in which case the example above will output `$stmt2`'s error twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return error message for each statement, in the case of OO style, `$stmt1->error` will return the last error message for `$stmt1`, and `$stmt2->error` will return the last error message for `$stmt2`.